# Swift Mailer Error on Linux

Tags: php, linux, symfony, swiftmailer

Using Swift mailer with Symfony. It works perfectly on windows but on linux there is an error:

Command:

```
 php app/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env=prod
```

Error:

```
 [ErrorException]                                                              
  Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in
 /var/www/html/KonnectEz/vendor/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/KeyCache/DiskKeyCache.php line 270

swiftmailer:spool:send [--message-limit[="..."]] [--time-limit[="..."]]
```

Comment: make sure the *www-data* user has enough access level in the path for swiftmail; also check the owner of the folder and make sure *www-data* is a part of that group is its owner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think SwiftMailer DiskKeyCache is unable to create the cache directory recursively.
Please check your SwiftMailer spool directory in config.yml and make sure this path exists.

[mkdir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) doesn't create directories recursivey by default and DiskKeyCache doesn't force this behaviour.

Maybe the spool directory exists in your windows environment, but not in your linux env?

Comment: Directory app/ectras/spool was missing in Linux. It worked after director creation

Comment: there is no conifg.yml file. where is it located?

Comment: Exception 'Swift_IoException' with message 'Failed to create cache directory C:\WINDOWS\TEMP/3db411e38b7749973b02417e483cf3c9' I am getting error why its trying to create in windows directory when I am on ubuntu ?